# How to compute CDF from a given PMF in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability-density, cdf, ecdf

For a given PMF `p=f(\theta)` for `\theta` between `0` and `2\pi`, i computed the CDF in Matlab as

```
theta=0:2*pi/n:2*pi
for i=1:n
cdf(i)=trapz(theta(1:i),p(1:i));
end
```

and the result is verified.

1. I tried to do the same with `cumsum` as `cdf=cumsum(p)*(2*pi)/n` but the result is wrong. why?
2. How can i compute the CDF if the given PMF is in 2D as`p=f(\theta,\phi)` ? Can i do it without going into detail as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689946/multivariate-inverse-transformation-sampling) ?

Comment: Is theta uniformly spaced in your example?  If not, using cumsum() will not work.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome I think it is, i did ```theta=0:2*pi/n:2*pi```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1D case you can use `cumsum` to get the vectorized version of loop (assuming that both `theta` and `p` are column vectors):

```
n = 10;
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, n).';
p = rand(n,1);
cdf = [0; 0.5 * cumsum((p(1:n-1) + p(2:n)) .* diff(theta(1:n)))];
```

In 2D case the function `cumsum` will be applied two times, in vertical and horizontal directions:

```
nthet = 10;
nphi = 10;
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, nthet).';     % as column vector
phi = linspace(0, pi, nphi);            % as row vector
p = rand(nthet, nphi);
cdf1 =  0.5 * cumsum((p(1:end-1, :) + p(2:end, :)) .* diff(theta), 1);
cdf2 =  0.5 * cumsum((cdf1(:, 1:end-1) + cdf1(:, 2:end)) .* diff(phi), 2);
cdf = zeros(nthet, nphi);
cdf(2:end, 2:end) = cdf2;
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  It worked in 1D. Just i wonder if we should compute somehow the marginal cdf or conditional for 2D case, as discussed in the link i cited above.